# Magento 1.9 collection multi conditions

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, product-collection

I read many posts and articles but still didn't find a solution.

I would like to filter my product collection with this condition:

```
... 
WHERE ('supplier_id' = 1 AND 'product_type' = 'first_type') 
OR ('supplier_id' = 2 AND 'product_type' = 'another_type') 
...
```

Is it possible to achieve this using **addFieldToFilter** method?

Any other suggestions are welcome as well!

Comment: use getSelect()->where() to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by this way, I think this will solve your problem

```
->getSelect()->where(" (`Your attribute` = 'Value' AND `Your attribute` = 'Value') OR (`Your attribute` = 'Value' AND `Your attribute` = 'Value')");
```

In your case in the getSelect() could be:

```
->getSelect()->where("(`supplier_id` = '1' AND `product_type` = 'first_type') OR (`supplier_id` = '2' AND `product_type` = 'another_type')");
```

Comment: Can I get any working example? I am not really sure how to implement it, cause I am getting empty array or error. And again, there is no much information on Google.

My whole query looks like this:
`$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->getSelect()->where("(supplier_id = '1' AND product_type = 'first_type') OR (supplier_id = '2' AND product_type = 'another_type')");`

Comment: first you check what you getting in collection, whether 'another_type' 'first_type' or 'supplier_id' attribute exist or not